# How to use CocosEditor in Clion

Tags: cocos2d-x, clion

I found [CocosEditor](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7433?pr=clion) and I download it. But after I put it into /plugins, it didn't work. 
If I import the Classes of my cocos project, the ide can't find the cocos2d.h